# Am I using git rebase correctly?

Tags: git

I have a remote repo with 3 commits (A , B, C). I want to remove commit B so that the repo commit history looks like (A, C). Here are the steps I've been taking to do this:

run the command `git rebase -i HEAD~3` which produces the following output in the vim editor

```
pick a3456bc commit A

pick ch7887j commit B

pick d45fffh commit C
```

2) edit the vim output to the following

```
pick a3456bc commit A

squash ch7887j commit B

pick d45fffh commit C
```

3) run the command `git push -f`

I've verified that the remote commit history appears to look fine, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something behind the scenes that I shouldn't be, and if there is a better way to go about this. Thanks

Comment: I think it's better to `git revert` commit B. This would give you A B C D, but with the content of only A C. The history is preserved.

Answer (score 1):

`squash` merges the commit with the previous commit. Thus, you are putting the changes of B into A. If you want to put them into C, keeping A intact, you want to pick B and squash C:

```
pick a3456bc commit A

pick ch7887j commit B

squash d45fffh commit C
```

Note that `squash` will allow you to edit the commit message, and the message will be initialized to both commit messages, so it is easy to pick which of the two messages you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You've taken all the changes made in B and squashed them in to A. If that was the goal, you're fine. However, if by " I want to remove commit B so that the repo commit history looks like (A, C)" you meant you don't want to keep the changes performed in B, you should simply remove the line for commit B in your `git rebase -i`:

```
pick a3456bc commit A
pick d45fffh commit C
```